# Device to device push notification firebase - onWrite issue

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have an android app and want people (authenticated users) to send push notification each other from a message box. I'm using node.js with firebase cloud functions and I got this **error** on logs:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined
>       at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:10:33)
>   ...

The message is successfully written to real-time database but the notification is not delivered to the receiver(user).

I read so many docs and same/similar problems so I'm aware that there are so many topics related to this but I couldn't solve the problem. I use [index.js](https://gist.github.com/mitchtabian/b1e96d1139823321482bf392c37fc854) as the source code but changed some parts like onWrite section according to the documents I read.

The error **indicates** this line in the following code:
`const receiverId = context.params.userId;`
Something about params go wrong. Here is the small part of the code(with my changings):

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');
let admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/{userId}/{messageId}').onWrite((change,context) => {

//get the userId of the person receiving the notification because we need to get their token
const receiverId = context.params.userId;
console.log("receiverId: ", receiverId);

//get the user id of the person who sent the message
const senderId = change.child('user_id').val();
console.log("senderId: ", senderId);

//get the message
const message = change.child('message').val();
console.log("message: ", message);

//get the message id. We'll be sending this in the payload
const messageId = context.params.messageId;
console.log("messageId: ", messageId);
```

`...`

Answer (score 0):

Get lastest version of node 
And see this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data for usage of onWrite(event...) and onCreate(.....)
That'll help you